# Finding a closed form for the recursive sequence $a_n=\frac13(10-2a_{n-1})$, with $a_0=3$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series

I've got following recursive sequence:
$$
a_n=\frac13(10-2a_{n-1})
$$
With $ a_0=3$

I have found following expression:

$$ a_n=3+ \sum_{n=0}^n{2^{n-1}\cdot\frac{5}{3^n}\cdot (-1)^n} $$

Is there maybe a better form?
Thank you for your help!
I would appreciate hints

Comment: Assuming your summation formula is correct, rewrite $2^{n-1}$ as $\frac{2^n}{2}$ and combine all the powers. You should get a familiar looking expression.

Comment: Your sum uses $n$ as both the index and the upper limit. You should fix that so they use different variables.

Comment: Also, hint: let $a_n = b_n +k$. Can you find a value of $k$ such that the recursion for $b_n$ is particularly simple?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $\,b_n=a_n-2\;\;$ for any $\,n\in\Bbb N\cup\{0\}\,.\;\;\left(\implies\color{brown}{b_0=1}\,\right)$

From $\,a_n=\dfrac{10-2a_{n-1}}3\;\;\forall n\in\Bbb N\;,\;$ we get that

$b_n+2=\dfrac{10-2\left(b_{n-1}+2\right)}3\;\;\;\forall n\in\Bbb N\;,$

$b_n=\dfrac{6-2b_{n-1}}3-2\;\;\;\forall n\in\Bbb N\;,$

$b_n=-\dfrac23b_{n-1}\;\;\;\forall n\in\Bbb N\;.$

Consequently ,

$b_n=-\dfrac23b_{n-1}=\left(-\dfrac23\right)^{\!2}\!b_{n-2}=\ldots=\left(-\dfrac23\right)^{\!n}\!b_0=\left(-\dfrac23\right)^{\!n}\;\;,$

$a_n=2+b_n=2+\left(-\dfrac23\right)^{\!n}\;\;$ for any $\,n\in\Bbb N\cup\{0\}\,.$

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: @Arthr, you are welcome !